# Call API on close of browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating project using angular. In my project i need to clear the session when user close the browser. I am doing this with below code

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  async ngOnDestroy()
  {
    await  this.someservice.logout.subscribe();
    debugger;
  }
```

But the problem is this api call never completed and session is not clearing.

Comment: How did the user close the browser? If I force quit / kill my browser you have **no chance** to clean up anything.

Comment: Yea,  need to do when user self click on the cross button @luk202

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon (page also contains an explanation why unload / beforeunload should be avoided to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

I have something a little different for when user closes the browser in order to clear out the localStorage. I am not using the var event but kept it just so I could see and play around with what does get passed in.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
unloadHandler(event: Event)
{
 localStorage.removeItem('storageName');
}
```

I have **not** had any issues with the above clearing out values.